# Terminating App due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException:Unsupported', reason 'Unsupported'

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error when i make build and run my app on IOS my app is in react native

Everything tried but all in vain

Node modules delete and install pods folder and podlockfile delete and pod install
All tried even build folder clean and creating main.jsbundle all solution applied nothing worked